# Interact with a DOM element when 'ref' is not available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-dom

I need to trigger a `.focus()` in a button, on a React component. But it comes from a 3rd party library and I can't use `ref`.

The only way I managed to do so far is by using setTimeout AND querySelector , as the element is not immediately available upon `componentDidMount`. Bellow is my current code:

```js
componentDidMount() {

  window.setTimeout(() => {
    const confirmButton = document.querySelector('.confirmButton');
    confirmButton && confirmButton.focus();
  }, 1);
}
```

Is there any other less ugly way of achieving that?

Comment: You can wrap that button inside a div element and then use refs on div.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add this extra div, but it sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I can send native props to the Button component

```diff
-  componentDidMount() {
-
-    window.setTimeout(() => {
-      const confirmButton = document.querySelector('.confirmButton');
-      confirmButton && confirmButton.focus();
-    }, 1);
-  }
-

...

<Button
+ autofocus
```